# Is there any tool that I can use to manage global data in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Recently I'm working in a basic project to learn a little bit more of flutter.

But I found a blocker... which is that I have to pass data consistently and updated between a widget and its parent, so I wonder if is there any tool or extension to add that let me manage global scopes in my widgets.

Something like redux o a similar concept... Is there any of it? How can I control data in a flutter project if I need to use them in different widgets?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you mean state management, get, bloc, provider are the best ones.

Comment: Yes, state management... I mean that... Did you say provider? I've heard about it.... get? bloc? Are those tools?

Comment: yes,  all 3 of them are used for state management, there's many more like, riverpod, mobx,binder

Comment: Sure, I'll search about it, thanks

Comment: most welcome ^^

Comment: My personal choice is Riverpod, as a nice middle ground between too simple and overly complex. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll search about it. This Riverpod... is a tool? a package to download?